# Использование enable_shared_from_this совместно с custom deleter

Tags: c++, smart-pointer, shared-ptr

Доброго времени суток.

Разбираюсь с `smart pointers`.

У `std::sharde_ptr` есть возможность указать пользовательский `deleter`.

Так же есть `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Возникли вопросы:

- Будет ли использоваться `custom deleter` после использования `shared_form_this`?
- Безопасно ли их совместное условие?
- Почему такой ответ?

Предполагаемое использование:

```cpp
// interface.hxx

#include <memory>

struct A
{
    using ptr = std::shared_ptr<A>;

    static ptr create();
    virtual ptr demo() = 0;

protected:
    static void destroy(A* a);
    virtual ~A();
};
```

```cpp
// interface.cxx

#include "interface.hxx"

struct B: A, std::enable_from_this()
{
    ptr demo() override
    {
        return shared_from_this(); // <<< Is it safe??
    }

};

A::~A() = default;

A::ptr A::create() { return {new B, &A::destroy}; }

void A::destroy(A* a)
{
    // some cleanup code

    delete a;
}
```

UPD0: Я хочу использовать эту связку, чтобы возвращать `shared_ptr` из `dll` и и при этом для создания/удаления использовался аллокатор из этой же `dll`

Comment: Конструкторы `shared_ptr` знают про `enable_shared_from_this`, поэтому custom deleter сохраняется. https://godbolt.org/z/eov8TzEMs

Comment: Custom deleter будет работать нормально. Но непонятно, какую проблему вы хотите решить. В обычной жизни вам достаточно использовать что-то вроде GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER в CMake и обычный new-delete/unique_ptr, и если вы используете плагины - нужно ещё следить, чтобы исключения и другие объекты удалялись раньше плагина. В остальном, проблемы ABI совместимости либо нет, либо вы не решите её таким образом уже хотя бы потому, что ваши функции не noexcept. Такой подход может иметь смысл разве что при использовании нестандартного аллокатора, но это не имеет отношения к dll.